# How towork with propelorm

Tags: php, propel

I am new to propel,any one can explain me about what is the use of it and how to integrate any framework with propel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since there is an entire [website](http://www.propelorm.org/) about Propel, full of [documentation](http://www.propelorm.org/wiki/Documentation/1.6) and the like, I'll bet they can.

You bigger question, I think, is that you probably want to understand what the purpose of an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) is. In short, it is a way of mapping between a relational database and an OOP framework, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) has far more information, so you might want to start there.

### EDIT

---

You mentioned in a comment that you'd like to combine this with CakePHP. Well here's how: don't unless you already know how to combine them. CakePHP has its own ORM system, so there really is no justifiable use case for having both (legacy code is not excuse -- just choose one!). If you're using Cake, use Cake and rejoice (you can have tea and skip on the `or death`)! If you're using Propel, use Propel and go somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

For such a general question, I'd point you to the official site - http://www.propelorm.org/

Their documentation is surprisingly robust.

Comment: Yes I had a look at that already ,but I am not sure how to integrate the cakephp with propel

Comment: That would have been a much better question / search. Based on your comment to a later question, it almost sounds like you're not sure what you want at this point.

Comment: Yes I agree with that, I need to create a propel application so what is my concern is can  we perform all operation with a help of propel alone? or do we need any other framework to do any further customization?

Comment: Well, from the Web site Propel is an ORM, so it'll make working with your database easier. However, that's not to say you couldn't use something that provided, for example, MVC support (so, making front-end development easier). See http://www.phpframeworks.com/ (unsure of when it was last updated) for a comparison. Note that CakePHP is listed at the above, so you may want to stick with that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [their website](http://www.propelorm.org/)? Here is a screenshot, this should do it. it's amazing what [Google](http://google.com) is capable of, don't be afraid to use it.

[image]